# How to make seaborn plot display and take multiplicity of points into account

Tags: plot, regression, seaborn, scatter-plot

I have these two lists of data extracted from a dataframe.

[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5] (Col 1)

[5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 5] (Col 2)

Calling stats.preasonr from the scipy library gives (-0.5062175977346661, 0.20052806464412476), indicating a negative correlation. However, the line of best fit calling

```
graph = sns.jointplot(x = 'col1name', y = 'col2name', data = df_name, kind = 'reg')
```

is positive. I realized that this is because I don't think that the calculation of the line of best fit is taking the multiplicity of the points into account. In particular, (5,2) is only considered once even if it happens 3 times. So what do I do that (a) someone can look at this plot and tell how many students are represented with a single data point and (b) the line of best fit takes into account the multiplicity of points?

Here is a picture of the plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The coinciding points aren't ignored.  Here is a visualization adding some random noise to show all points, and marking the mean of 'col2' for each value in 'col1'. Also the r-value is calculated before applying the random jitter.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5],
                   'col2': [5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 5]})
r, p = pearsonr(df['col1'], df['col2'])
xs = np.unique(df['col1'])
ys = [df[df['col1'] == x]['col2'].mean() for x in xs]
df['col1'] += np.random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1, len(df))
df['col2'] += np.random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1, len(df))
g = sns.jointplot(x='col1', y='col2', data=df, kind='reg')
g.ax_joint.scatter(x=xs, y=ys, marker='X', color='crimson') # show the means
g.ax_joint.text(2.5, 4.5, f'$r={r:.2f}$', color='navy') # display the r-value
plt.show()
```

[image: jointplot with scatter and means per column]

The regression line seems to go quite close to the means, as expected. For `col1==5` there are 4 values at 5, 2 at 4 and 3 at 2, their mean is 3.78.